# "public class Foo" v.s. "class Foo" in Groovy domain classes

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

The following Groovy code creates a GORM-persisted domain class called Foo when written to grails-app/domain/Foo.groovy:

```
class Foo {
  String someField
}
```

However, if I instead write "public class Foo" the class does NOT get GORM-persisted (i.e. no save() method injected, no database table created, etc.):

```
public class Foo {
  String someField
}
```

I'm running the latest stable release of Grails (1.1).

Question: **Is this a bug or is it the expected behaviour? Why?**

**Update #1:** Related sub-question: Am I the only one hitting this problem? It would be nice to know if anyone else is able to replicate this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy classes are public by default (likewise for Groovy methods), so there should be no change in behaviour if you add `public`. However, I cannot reproduce this behaviour/bug in Grails 1.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug.

I'd enter the details into JIRA and get the answer from the source.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS

Comment: Thanks for your pointer to the Grails JIRA. Are you able to replicate the problem?

Comment: I'm running 1.0.4 and it doesn't have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting this behavior on 1.3.3

check the "isDomainClass" method in DomainClassArtefactHandler.groovy. you will see (at least in 1.3.3) the only types that are excluded are closures and enums